# Fits file handling and updating

Tags: python, astropy, fits

I want to correct the header and the disposition of data content of a fits file.
I show in the next script the way I am trying to update the fits.

```py
cubefits = 'data.fits'
hdul = fits.open(cubefits,mode='update')
hdul.info()
hdul.readall()  
hd   = hdul[0].header
data = hdul[0].data
```

NAXIS1  =                  761
NAXIS2  =                 1297
NAXIS3  =                  833

`data.shape = (833,1297,761)`

I notice that the header does not match the data shape, so, I rearrange it as follows:

```py
data_new = np.moveaxis( data,0,2 )
data_new = np.moveaxis( data_new,0,1 )
hdul[0].data = data_new
```

where data_new.shape = (761,1297,833).
Then, I close to save `hdul.close()`.

But when I load it again the `hdul[0].data.shape` is correct but the data are mixed up and

NAXIS1  =                  833
NAXIS2  =                 1297
NAXIS3  =                  761

Comment: `data_new = np.transpose(data, (2, 1, 0))` makes the right shape but the header is still wrong

Answer (score 0):

I found out, that it is just the standard disposition of the fits data.
NAXIS1 corresponds to the 0 axes in the data array.